# c# Blob Triggered Azure Function V1 with "App Service Plan" is triggered with some delay

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am using azure function V1 and created a Blob Triggered function under it.
As it is a blob triggered azure function, I am expecting that it will be triggered as soon as I place some file in blob container.

But that is not what happening. Sometimes it is getting triggered immediately and some times it is taking delay of 10 seconds and some times taking delay up yo 1 or 2 minutes.

I am not getting why it is happening.

I have searched about it and found that so many other developers are also getting the same issue.

But I am not able to find any Microsoft official documentation or explanation for this issue.

Can anyone explain the problem and give solution.

It will help me a lot if anyone can give any Microsoft official documentation on this.

Thank You.

**27.12.2018**

**How I observed this issue?**

I have one application "App1". This is placing 5 files on my blob container every second. There is a blob triggered function "BT1" on that container.

In "App1" I have written a code to log the time after putting the file in blob container. And in "BT1" my first line is the code to log the blob trigger execution start time.

When I observe this two logs, I see 10 seconds of delay regularly. And in some case It is going little high.

[image]

Comment: We usually meet delay caused by [cold start in Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#latency-issues), which is not expected in the dedicated App service plan with `Always on`(in Application settings) turned on. If the container is monitoring >10000 blobs, the delay is also [expected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---polling).

Comment: @JerryLiu Thank you for showing interest to support me. What you are saying is true. That is all what I get on internet. But practically by blob triggered function is triggered with some delay. I have added some more information in my question to explain how I have observed this issue.

Comment: Better look into function itself logs(on kudu `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugCo‌​nsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host`) to see whether the problem roots in function side.